# how to get a timestamp of another timezone in java or JODA

Tags: java, jodatime

i want to get current time (now) from Different time zone .

for example using joda datetime library,

I can get Australian time zone like using JODA datetime

```
DateTime zoned = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Australia/Melbourne"));
```

and its current time Using

```
DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("Australia/Melbourne"));
```

if i want to convert this DateTime object into java.sql.Timestamp object

,i have to get its milliseconds using

getMillis method of DateTime class to instantaite new Timestamp Object

```
Timestamp zonedStamp = new TimeStamp(zoned.getMillis());
```

so every time the passed milliseconds since the epoch time would be the same logically for each timezone.

**My question is how i can get Autralian Time zone's current time to get a zoned Timestamp Object.**

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Comment: Do you mean the `Timestamp` should have the value equivalent to Austalian current time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `Timestamp` object with **Australian timezone equivalent time value** then try below:

```
    Date currentTime = new Date();
    DateFormat ausFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    ausFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Melbourne"));

    //get the time string in australian timezone
    String ausTime  = ausFormat.format(currentTime);

    //Convert the above time string in local date object
    DateFormat currentFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    //optional: set the timezone as Asia/Calcutta
    currentFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
    Date ausTimeInLocal = currentFormat.parse(ausTime);

    //get the time stamp object using above date object
    Timestamp ausTimeStampInLocal = new Timestamp(ausTimeInLocal.getTime());
```

Comment: This will still give Timestamp in local/default timezone. This is because DatFormat.format() and parse() output and read from the configured timezone (DateFormat.setTimeZone()) to local timezone.

java.util.Date is not the right class when you want to deal with timezones. Use java.util.Calendar instead.

Saying that, the only solution would be to switch your default timezone (TimeZone.setDefaultZone()) which may not be favorable mid process. Timezones should be configured in my opinion only at startup.

Comment: Thanks Yogendra . Mr. sgp15 you r right but though you r setting different time zone from the start , the milliseconds would be the same logically whether you use JODA , UTIL or Calendar class , My concern is to get milliseconds of different timezone 's time so i can instantiate Timestamp based on it.thanks for oyur comments.

Comment: Hello Yogendra I have noticed that above code gives me the differenc of 4 hours , actually Indian Standard Time and Melbourne time has difference of 4.30 hours. can you advice me why ?

Comment: @Mihir: Try setting the appropriate timezone. Also you may want to set the timezone in `currentFormat` as well.

Comment: @Yogendra Time zone is appropriately. It is the same which you used in Example.

Comment: @Mihir: I think I got the problem. Remove `z` from the format as it appends the timezone in the date string, which affects the second conversion.

Comment: @YogendraSingh I have removed z , now it gives difference of 5.30 hours instead of 4.30 hours. it shows now the Sydney time difference.have you test it ?

Comment: @Mihir Its working correctly. There a `DayLightSaving(DST)` in effect which is increasing the difference by +1. Best way to verify is to check the `Australian Time` on website such as http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo.tzc?s=default&tz=Australia/Melbourne and compare to your local time.

Comment: Ok done it is the offset of DST until 7 Apr , 2013 which causes this +1. thanks