# UTC Timestamp + Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to get the UTC TimeStamp in a simple Java program using Joda:

```
public Timestamp getCurrentUTC(LocalDateTime date, DateTimeZone srcTZ, DateTimeZone dstTZ, Locale l) {
    DateTime srcDateTime = date.toDateTime(srcTZ);
    DateTime dstDateTime = srcDateTime.toDateTime(dstTZ);
    
    System.out.println("UTC Time:" + dstDateTime.getMillis());      
    System.out.println("UTC Time:" + new Timestamp(dstDateTime.getMillis()));
    
    return new Timestamp(dstDateTime.getMillis());
}
```

The output of the program is as follows:

```
UTC Time:1378265162047
UTC Time:2013-09-03 23:26:02.047
```

The millisecond value is the correct UTC time (i.e. confirmed with `GMT-4` timezone)
The second value is the `EST` timezone.

What I need is the UTC value unchanged as `java.sql.Timestamp` (ie TZ independent),
for a database write. Is this possible?

## Edit 1

```
DateTime srcDateTime = date.toDateTime(srcTZ);

DateTime dstDateTime = srcDateTime.toDateTime(dstTZ);

System.out.println("UTC Time:" + dstDateTime.getMillis());
```

I know that `srcDateTime` is the local date (GMT-4), and `dstDateTime` is
UTC (GMT-0). Output values of the dates are as follows:

```
Source Date:2013-09-04T09:10:43.683-04:00

Destination Date: 2013-09-04T13:10:43.683Z
```

I tried all the combinations to try to get the UTC value of `dstDateTime` as a java.sql.TimeStamp:

```
System.out.println("UTC Time:" + dstDateTime.getMillis());
    
System.out.println("UTC Time:" + new Timestamp(srcDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis()));

System.out.println("UTC Time:" + new Timestamp(dstDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis()));
```

The print output for testing:

```
UTC Time:1378298760226 - Correct UTC

UTC Time:2013-09-04 08:46:00.226 - Incorrect Local Date Time instead of the Expected UTC

UTC Time:2013-09-04 08:46:00.226 - Incorrect Local Date Time instead of the Expected UTC
```

The first print line is the correct UTC timestamp. All I need is that same value
as type java.sql.TimeStamp. Anything I tried always returned the local date time
of the machine.

## Edit 2

I tried the following:

```
System.out.println("UTC Timestamp:" + date.toDateTime(srcTZ).getMillis());
System.out.println("UTC Timestamp:" + new Timestamp(date.toDateTime(srcTZ).getMillis()));
```

The output is as follows:

```
UTC Time:1378342856315 - Correct UTC Time
UTC Timestap:2013-09-04 21:00:56.315 - Local Time other than the expected UTC Time
```

Whenever I try to convert to TimeStamp, I loose the valid UTC value that I am after.

In terms of the method's parameters:

```
srcTZ = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Montreal")
dstTZ = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"))
Local l = new Locale("en", "CA")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Nick.

## Edit 3

Hello Matt,

Thank you so much for your response. We are getting the same results as you. Did not know the thing about printing etc.. More specifically:

```
System.out.println("UTC Timestamp:" + srcDateTime.toDateTime(dstTZ).getMillis());
System.out.println("UTC Timestamp:" + srcDateTime.toDateTime(dstTZ));
System.out.println("UTC Timestamp:" + new Timestamp(srcDateTime.toDateTime(dstTZ).getMillis()));
```

Yields The Output:

```
UTC Timestamp:1378389098468 - Correct UTC Timestap (Thu, 05 Sep 2013 13:51:38 GMT)
UTC Timestamp:2013-09-05T13:51:38.468Z - Correct UTC Time
UTC Timestamp:2013-09-05 09:51:38.468 - Local time is printed, UTC is expected
```

The problem was brought to my attention when we realized that the DB was storing the local time instead of UTC:

```
+---------------------+
| effectivedate       |
+---------------------+
| 2013-09-05 09:34:11 |
+---------------------+
```

The Mysql timezone is set to '-00:00'

```
mysql> SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
+---------------------+
| CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |
+---------------------+
| 2013-09-05 13:48:09 |
+---------------------+
```

Debugging the application using eclipse debugger we realized that the local date time (2013-09-05 09:51:38.468) was being passed to the DB (Can't post images, not enough points...). The datatype is straight TimeStamp, with no string manipulation. Maybe the eclipse debugger is using `String.println()` function as well, not sure..

I really appreciate all the help debugging our application. Did not want to take up so much time (no pun intended) and effort...

Kind Regards,

Nick.

Comment: "The millisecond value is the correct UTC time (ie GMT-4)" This statement doesn't make sense to me.  Isn't UTC time always GMT-0?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13539088/180100) might help

Comment: Hello tie, sorry, I fixed the working. I meant calculate against local TZ GMT-4. I am trying to get GMT-0 as TimeStamp. RC, toString will not work. We need it in timestamp. I know that toSTring returns the right value.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I hope this saves someone 3 days of bullshit. Set the default timezone somewhere logical in your code. Makes things more portable that having to set an env variable etc.. You can do this by adding the following somewhere logical to your code, Constructor etc..:

DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.UTC);

You can print UTC, concatenate UTC whatever...

Comment: Incase you are not using Joda time throughout your code, then you need to also set [`TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/ut‌​il/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone). You can also just set the user.timezone system property to get both in one pass. If you set TimeZone (using system property or calling the code) before touching any Joda code then it will pick up your setting. See my comment to my answer a few days ago for setting the `TimeZone`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this short program, it should illustrate what is going on:

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.getDefault();

System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(tz);
System.out.println("-----");
System.out.println(date.toDateTime(tz));
System.out.println(date.toDateTime(tz).toInstant());
System.out.println(date.toDateTime(tz).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC));
System.out.println("-----");
System.out.println(date.toDateTime(tz).getMillis());
System.out.println(date.toDateTime(tz).toInstant().getMillis());
System.out.println(date.toDateTime(tz).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis());
System.out.println("-----");
System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.toDateTime(tz).getMillis()));
System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.toDateTime(tz).toInstant().getMillis()));
System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.toDateTime(tz).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis()));
```

On my computer, it outputs:

```
2013-09-04T19:08:35.111
America/Phoenix
-----
2013-09-04T19:08:35.111-07:00
2013-09-05T02:08:35.111Z
2013-09-05T02:08:35.111Z
-----
1378346915111
1378346915111
1378346915111
-----
2013-09-04 19:08:35.111
2013-09-04 19:08:35.111
2013-09-04 19:08:35.111
```

As you can see, you can get to the UTC time with either `.toInstant()`, or with `.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)`.  But even if you call *neither* of these, you will still get the UTC value when you call `getMillis()`.

So the problem isn't with JodaTime.  The problem is in how you are evaluating your results.

When you create a `java.sql.Timestamp`, you're passing in the milliseconds from 1/1/1970 UTC.  It's only when you *display* it that it is applying the local time zone to the result.

Assuming you are passing it to a database as a `Timestamp` and not doing some interm string representation, then you should be fine.  Just because it looks like the local time when you call `System.out.println`, doesn't mean that it is a local time internally.

The `java.sql.Timestamp` class extends `java.util.Date` - which is where it gets this behavior from.

Comment: Hello Matt, please see Edit 3 above

Comment: If your `Timestamp` is getting saved in local time, perhaps you are building your SQL query with string concatenation instead of passing proper parameters?  Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for hours and finally found a solution.

I'm using PlayFramework - not sure if this will help anyone, but for my database connection setting I had to use:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/continuum?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC"
```

(add the '&serverTimezone=UTC')

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the UTC value or can you simply use the Timestamp.toString() method? this will give you a formatted time string for use in SQL statements.

Comment: I know that the toString method will work, however we need it in java.sql.TimeStamp.

Answer (score 0):

`LocalDateTime` already excludes the timezone, which means that it either means literally the local time where the user enters "their" time (e.g., for a funeral invitation, which will always be in the local time) or it is already in UTC if you planned ahead.

If your `date` is already in the `srcTZ`'s `DateTimeZone`, but loaded as `LocalDateTime`, then you should return

```
new Timestamp(date.toDateTime(srcTZ).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis());
```

Alternatively, if you are sure that the `date` is already in UTC, which is GMT+0, then you can return

```
new Timestamp(date.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).getMillis());
```

Finally, most databases accept the timestamp as an ISO formatted string, which is the default `toString` output:

```
date/*.toDateTime(srcTZ)*/.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).toString()
```

Comment: Hello Picky, please see above *edit*. I tried all combinations that you suggested, and all of them return the local time when converting to java.sql.timestamp not the needed UTC to write to the DB.

Comment: We do pass the LocalDateTime timezone excluded local time to the function however, do the correct offset within the function using DateTime: DateTime srcDateTime = date.toDateTime(srcTZ);
  DateTime dstDateTime = srcDateTime.toDateTime(dstTZ);

Comment: @NickCameo Time is particularly hard because of timezones. This is why I tend to always use UTC and convert to timezones as late as possible (at the presentation layer). To the point, if `date` is in a timezone such as EST/GMT-4, then you need to convert to a `DateTime` object that has that timezone, which should be the first step `toDateTime(srcTZ)`. At this point, you should have the actual date/time in its actual timezone. From there you don't actually need to do `toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)`, but you should be able to use `getMillis()` as in `date.toDateTime(srcTZ).getMillis()`.

Comment: Shy of that, can you give example values for your `date`, `srcTZ` and even the `dstTZ`?

Comment: @ pickypg Please see "Edit 2"

Comment: Set your default `TimeZone` to be UTC/GMT: [`TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)). This only needs to be done once, preferably at startup.  To avoid writing code, you can also set the [`"user.timezone"` system property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2493805/706724), which will set it (use `-Duser.timezone=GMT` for UTC).