# Joda DateTime getMillis() for UTC is incorrect, returning local milliseconds instead

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to get the UTC milliseconds to convert a [Joda `DateTime` instance](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) to a [SQL Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), however it is converting it to my local time instead.

This is an example:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
Timestamp t = new Timestamp(d.getMillis());
System.out.println(t);
t.setHours(d.getHourOfDay());
System.out.println(t);
```

And the output:

```
2015-04-17 18:11:27.277
2015-04-17 22:11:27.277
```

Why is it converted to my local timezone?  I thought the `DateTime.getMillis()` method always returned the milliseconds for UTC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTC Timestamp + Joda Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604989/utc-timestamp-joda-time)

Answer (score 4):

When you change the time, you don't change the number of milliseconds since the epoch. In other words, calling `withZone` doesn't actually change the underlying `long millis`.

The real problem is the `Timestamp.setHours` method, which has been deprecated since Java 1.1. See the documentation:

> @Deprecated
>
> public void setHours(int hours)
>
> **Deprecated.** As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by `Calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, int hours)`.
>   Sets the hour of this Date object to the specified value. This Date object is modified so that it represents a point in time within the specified hour of the day, with the year, month, date, minute, and second the same as before, as interpreted in the local time zone.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime d = DateTime.now();
Timestamp t = new Timestamp(d.getMillis());
System.out.println(t);
t.setHours(d.getHourOfDay());
System.out.println(t);
```